# Failed to load PostCSS config

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite, postcss

I migrated from Vue2 to vue3 and cli to vite (with Vuetify) and then get this error.

> [plugin:vite:css] Failed to load PostCSS config (searchPath: ...): [Error] Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: require() of ES Module C:\Users...\src\vue\node_modules\vuetify\lib\framework.mjs not supported.
> Instead change the require of C:\Users...\src\vue\node_modules\vuetify\lib\framework.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

> router.js:1
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
> App.vue:1
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
> main.css:1
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

I tried to delete modules and reinstall it, also tried to add postcss.config.js file but nothing worked for me

***package.json***

```
  "versionMessage": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve-dev": "vue-cli-service serve --mode development",
    "build-dev": "vue-cli-service build --mode development",
    "build-prod": "vue-cli-service build --mode production",
    "prep-deploy": "node prep_deployment.js",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "test": "vite test",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore --fix src"
  },
  "main": "background.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/compat": "^3.1.0-0",
    "color-hash": "^1.0.3",
    "gantt-elastic": "^1.0.10",
    "humanize-duration": "^3.21.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mathjs": "^7.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "throttled-queue": "^1.0.7",
    "vue": "^3.1.0-0",
    "vue-cookies": "^1.5.13",
    "vue-google-charts": "^0.3.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vue-session": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-timeago": "^5.1.2",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.23.2",
    "vuetify": "^3.1.5",
    "vuetify-upload-button": "^2.0.2",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.11.2",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.1.0-0",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.7.1",
    "lite-server": "^2.5.4",
    "mkdirp": "^1.0.3",
    "ncp": "^2.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.23.7",
    "stylus": "^0.54.7",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vite": "^4.1.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.8",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "no-console": "off",
      "no-unused-vars": "off"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

***vite.config.js***

````
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

const path = require("path");
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': require('path').resolve(__dirname, 'src')
        }
      },
    extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.json', '.vue'],
})```
````

Answer (score 9):

For any one running in to this problem :

this a new problem with how latest versions of vite treat ESM (Es modules).

CommonJS files need to be explicitly named as `.cjs`

rename the files to `postcss.config.cjs` and `tailwind.config.cjs` (if your are using tailwind) as a workaround.

good luck,
[source](https://github.com/BuilderIO/qwik/issues/836#issuecomment-1193114640)

Answer (score 1):

Manage to fix by myself when i added this in vite.config.js

```
    css: {
    postcss: {
        plugins: [
            postcssNesting
        ],
    },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Including `"type": "module",` in my package.json works for me, you can try it also.